# Changing default colours of CPTPieChart

Tags: ios, core-plot, cptxygraph

In CorePlot if you create a `CPTPieChart` object the default colours for the data slices seem to be green, red, blue.

How can I change them? Here is a code snippet I am using to create the graph..

```
pieChartGraph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.pieChartgraphHostView.bounds];
peChart.dataSource = self;
//... code 
// pieChart addSublayer:

self.dataForChart = [@[@25.0, @25.0, @48.0, @2.0] mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement one of the following datasource methods:

```
-(nullable CPTFill *)sliceFillForPieChart:(nonnull CPTPieChart *)pieChart recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
-(nullable NSArray *)sliceFillsForPieChart:(nonnull CPTPieChart *)pieChart recordIndexRange:(NSRange)indexRange;
```

Provide the fill for the slice with the given index. If the datasource returns `nil`, the default fill is used. If the datasource returns an `NSNull` object, no fill is drawn for the slice at that index.